# (C++) Add randomness to quicksort on equal elements

Tags: c++, random, quicksort

I'm using the following code to sort elements in a std.vector

```
struct element {
    int order;
    int someValue;
};

int comp( element a, element b ) {
    if (a.order < b.order)
        return true;
    return (rand() % 2) == 0;
}

vector.quickSort(comp);
```

is this code correct if I'm trying to add randomness on the elements that have the same ***order*** value

Comment: vector has no quickSort member function

Comment: @Mitch Wheat Let's say the elements' order is a decreasing counter, then I need to pick an element at random from that array with it's counter in zero and then reset it to a given value. If I can manage to sort the array each time I need to pick one element  that would do the job

Comment: @billz ups! I forgot to mention I'm using a btAlignedObjectArray from Bullet Physics' library, that has a quicksort method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this code correct.

You should really write a test with some data to check that.

---

If you would write a test you would see something wrong and know why, if we look at

```
if (a.order < b.order)
    return true;
return (rand() % 2) == 0;
```

you can see that the `a.order > b.order` case is missing which is why it will incorrectly work for that case, we can fix this by doing this instead which focuses on the exceptional case instead and leaves the other two cases to their default behavior (checking the order):

```
if (a.order == b.order)
    return (rand() % 2) == 0;
else
    return a.order < b.order;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, very educational answer